# Which Android Chart library I should Chose

Tags: android, charts

I just make a Pie Chart like below in Android System.
But i don't know which Chart library I should choose.
I try AchartEngine.But it not work.It can't do lots of things

I need the library can set X cordinate Unit,Y cordinate Unit.Like Day 1,Day 2;But AChartEngine can't do that.
I need draw a 3d Chart Engine below.

[image: picture]

j4lChartAndroid can do that ?or anything else can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this 
http://steema.com/entry/60

and following

Java related charts

J4L charts
artful bits charts
steema charts
afreecharts
android plot
achart engine charts
Using Javascript charts are build . Below i have mentioned them

mcharts
opengl
fusion charts ... like this you can have many more building charts using javascript

Answer (score 1):

For 3D charts I can suggest [Orson Charts for Android](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/android/index.html) (commercial, not free).